# Is $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-1)$

Tags: field-theory

> Is
>
> $$\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-1)$$

I know that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Q}(i)$ but I can't say that $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2-1) \cong \mathbb{Q}(1) = \mathbb{Q}$ since $X^2-1$ is not irreducible.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ is a field iff $p(x)$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show that the coset of $x-1$ is a zero divisor in the latter ring. Hence you can conclude that it is not a field.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is not a field. Its a ring with additive group $\mathbb{Q}\oplus\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I know what you mean, but you do realize that $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is also a ring with additive group $\Bbb{Q}\oplus\Bbb{Q}$ :-)

Comment: Good point. I was just too lazy to work out the multiplication in this case.

Comment: Besides there are four square roots of unity, $1,-1,x,-x$.